# How to restore Mysql Backup from dump file?

Tags: mysql

I am using `Mysql version 5.6` ,
i have dumpbackup file in `c:` drive names b.sql.
i opend Mysql5.6 command line cliente  it gave me promp like "Mysql>"
and my syntex is

```
mysql> -uroot -p1234 fabrication < c://b.sql;
```

err: you have an erron in sql syntex;
please help me

Comment: Have you tried `./ C:\b.sql` or `source C:\b.sql`?

Comment: yes i have same error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If it's a dump file that you created using `mysqldump`, then you can build a new database from the dump file using the `source` command.  Just login to MySQL using `mysql -p`, enter the root mysql password, then type: `source /path/to/mysqldumpfile`

Comment: one thing i want know that this dump file i was created by other host so can i restor in other host also?

Comment: Does it show you the line from the dump file that is causing the 1064 error?

Comment: no but now it saying the system canot find the specified file ?

Comment: C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.1\bin>mysql -u root -p 1234 fabric < c:/b.sql;

Comment: instead of that, try `mysql -p`.  Login to mysql, then type `source /path/to/dump/file`.